# How can I check regex for three patterns in one

Tags: regex

I have a string past in and would like to check if the string contains a certain pattern to ignore.

```
Input Strings: abckkk or abc_aa or abc2
```

I am looking for a regex to check the string contains kkk or ends with _aa or ends with a number.

```
Output: If any string match one of the above should be ignored.
```

Comment: That is my question about how to write regex. I am still beginner of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `|` to indicate "or". So in your specific example, I believe this will do:

```
(k{3})|(_aa)$|[0-9]+$
```

Match 3 consecutive "ks" anywhere or match a line ending with "_aa" or match a line ending with any number.

`$` ends with
`+` match 1 or more of the preceding

Answer (score 1):

A pipe can be used as an OR in regex.

And a [wordboundary](https://regular-expressions.mobi/wordboundaries.html?wlr=1) `\b` indicates a transition between a word character and something else.
So it can be used to check it's at the end of a word.

```
\w*(kkk\w*|_aa|\d)\b
```

[test](https://regexr.com/48mjj)

Answer (score 0):

try regex Something like this : `/abckkk|abc_aa|abc2/`.

This might help you out.. Thanks